# Where can I find the pde extension written by Andrew Richards for WinDBG?

Tags: windbg

I saw it mentioned on a few resources on the web, but I cannot find it. It does not seem to be included with WinDBG distribution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a public OneDrive that contains a ZIP file of it:

https://onedrive.live.com/?authkey=%21AJeSzeiu8SQ7T4w&id=DAE128BD454CF957%217152&cid=DAE128BD454CF957

Comment: By the way, I got the location of the above OneDrive from this video from Andrew Richards, in which he talks about the PDE extension as well: https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-167-Debugging-User-Mode-Crash-Dumps-Redux

Comment: Update: You will still need to download it from OneDrive. You can see it in the following video from february 2022: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=52c1QIW6niE&list=PLLhSArDiaW6IgzMYEMaEf_BF2yQN40fIm&index=7. The OneDrive Link can also been found in the description here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/shows/defrag-tools/.

Comment: Where do I put this file?  I am not going to watch a video.

Comment: How to use the dll?